# Bundling python dependencies in the project folder itself so as it can be easily shared and start application without downloading any dependencies

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Whenever we download any python dependencies i.e django,MySQL by using 'pip' it get install in the root folder that would be c drive on windows( where we have install python).

How can I install this dependencies in my project folder itself, so when I start my application it will read the dependencies from project folder rather from c drive.

My purpose is whenever i give my application to user or third person he should directly start application instead of downloading all dependencies.

Comment: Use Virtual Environments and generate requirements.txt files.

Comment: I have used freeze to generate requirement file. But my requirement is installing all dependencies and code in one folder and give it to user, so he only has to run it instead of setting things up and download dependencies again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go install [VirtualEnvWrapper](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) first. After that, create a new virtualenv, activate it, and run pip freeze. You should see nothing in there because nothing is installed. This env will store all your pip installs and will not use all the packages you have installed on your c drive. Anything you pip install while this env is activated will be in this env and this env alone. You can tie a project to this env as well by using commands from virtaulenvwrapper. Your env and project directories should be separate. Deactivate the env to go back to your 'Base' environment and pip freeze again. You will see all the installs you have done on your C drive.

A best practice is to create a requirements.txt file and version control it so everyone can use the same versions of the same packages. If you don't want to do this, simply activate your new virtual env and pip install everything you want.